# Find with fields set does not display correctly (node.js and mongodb)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The nodejs code to find documents doesn't work as intended:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("mydb");
  dbo.collection("customers").find({}, { _id: 0, name: 1 } ).toArray(function(err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
      console.log(result);
    db.close();
  });
});
```

I get the following warning:

```
(node:5540) [DEP0079] DeprecationWarning: Custom inspection function on Objects via .inspect() is deprecated
```

I'm following this tutorial and using the exact code: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_find.asp. I can only display one record using find one or display all, but when I use the codes in the "find some" section of the tutorial, I get the square brackets "[]" or all documents are displayed.

Comment: You "should" be using the [`project()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Cursor.html#project) method instead, however the message here is because the `beta` version is released on `npm` and you're not really meant to have installed it. Somebody messed up.

Comment: You can fix the package dependency by installing an exact "stable" version. `npm i -E mongodb@3.0.8`

Comment: As for "learning how to write queries". Start with the manual rather than w3schools - [Query Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/)

Comment: LTS is failing to install and it's not giving me any error messages. I installed the nodejs v10.1.0 (includes npm 5.6.0). Is that a beta version?

Comment: Node is okay, but you should replace the `mongodb` module you have downloaded with the one I specify above. This will probably be fixed in a few days and it's just a warning message anyway.

Comment: I've downgraded from node v10.1.0 to v8.11.2 LTS. It installs npm 5.6.0 with it also. After the downgrade, no warning is displayed but the find still doesn't work as intended. The command you mentioned to downgrade doesn't do anything, it still says version 5.6.0. I'm using Win Pro 10.

Comment: I've completely removed the beta version of mongodb and npm list gives me: mongodb@3.0.8 and mongodb-core@3.0.8. Find some still doesn't work as intended.

Comment: Tried project() and it works perfectly fine, the field specified is the only one displayed. I still don't understand why the code in w3c doesn't work, it follows the syntax as specified in the MongoDB manual.